# When does this @Scheduled(cron = "0 0 0/24 * * ?") get called?

Tags: java, spring, cron, scheduler, cron-task

I found this `@Scheduled(cron = "0 0 0/24 * * ?")` on top of a scheduler. Also there was a comment saying this runs every day. But i am not convinced how.

I know that Cron expression looks like

```
<minute> <hour> <day-of-month> <month> <day-of-week> <command>
```

But I am not able to relate 0/24 to . Can anyone add here?

Comment: check http://www.cronmaker.com/?7

Comment: I would rather refer to: https://spring.io/blog/2020/11/10/new-in-spring-5-3-improved-cron-expressions (and links) .. 1st parameter refers to seconds ..and `0/24` in your case would mean at 0 and at 24 o'clock (which is nonsense/double execution/even lagal!?)

Comment: 0/24 mean start at 0 o'clock and repeat it after 24 hours

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cron expression:

```
<Seconds> <Minutes> <Hours> <Day Of Month> <Month> <Day Of Week> <Year>
```

You can refer to:

`* * * ? * *    Every second`

`0 * * ? * *    Every minute`

`0 0 13 * * ?  At 13:00:00pm every day`

`0 0 */6 ? * *  Every six hours`

`0 0 * ? * *    Every hour`

Comment: That means, if we want to run it at 2am everyday, we can simply write it as  @Scheduled(cron = "0 0 2 * * ?"). Right?

Comment: @Deepak That's right.

Answer (score 2):

Refer to [Spring Docs](https://spring.io/blog/2020/11/10/new-in-spring-5-3-improved-cron-expressions). Spring's Cron expression is different with linux.
It's look like:

```
<Seconds> <Minutes> <Hours> <DayofMonth> <Month> <DayofWeek> <Year>
```

0/24 mean start at 0 o'clock and repeat it after 24 hours

Comment: That means, if we want to run it at 2am everyday, we can simply write it as  @Scheduled(cron = "0 0 2 * * ?"). Right?